# Does readelf return RPATH as RUNPATH?

Tags: 20.04, cmake

I have written a simple program/lib combo using cmake, named "PrintFive".

Running from the CLI:

```bsh
readelf -d PrintFive 

Dynamic section at offset 0x2d60 contains 30 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libUsesSharedLib.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/xxx/Projects/PrintFive/UsesSharedLib/sharedLib/lib:/home/xxx/Projects/PrintFive/build/UsesSharedLib]
 ...
```

Strange. My understanding is that CMake will write RPATH. It does not appear, but "RUNPATH" does.

If I run the application from the CLI, it has no problem locating this library.

If I remove the RUNPATH property:

```bsh
chrpath -d PrintFive
```

Then the app no longer runs. No surprises.
And if I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point at the location of the library then it all works again.

(at this point I rebuild my program)

If this "RUNPATH" was a true `RUNPATH` then I should be able to override it using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
Or so [this article](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling) claims.

So I run from the app's build directory:

```bsh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
```

(note that with cmake builds, libraries are not put in the same directory as the app)

Following the theory, the app should now not run because LD_LIBRARY_PATH should override any true RUNPATH baked into the binary.

Yet it runs.
That to me suggests that the binary does have RPATH.

I have two theories.

1. readelf returns RPATH as RUNPATH
2. readelf does not print RPATH even though the binary has it baked in.

Additional information:

```bsh
readelf -v
GNU readelf (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I have seen many internet articles showing readelf printing RPATH though.
Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your reasoning about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is wrong. When looking for libraries, the dynamic linker searches various locations in a definite order:

1. RPATH
2. LD_LIBRARY_PATH
3. RUNPATH
4. /etc/ld.so.cache
5. in the default paths /lib and /usr/lib (or lib64, depending on some compilation settings of glibc)

This does not mean the search stops after step 2 unconditionally if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set. It just means that if a suitable library is found at step 2, then step 3 and following are skipped.